# A forward pass batted from one receiver multiple times, eventually to another

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

The quarterback makes a forward pass to the first wide receiver who bats the ball foward, then the same receiver retouches the ball and bats the ball again toward a second receiver.

Is it legal? Or can the WR bat the ball forward only one time?

Comment: Is the batting deliberate, or an attempt to catch the ball which just happens to send the ball forwards?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the players are in bounds and the ball doesn't hit the ground. It appears to be a legal catch. There doesn't appear to be a limit on tips/bats of the ball.

> [ARTICLE 7. LEGAL TOUCHING](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#rule8)
>
> A forward pass (legal or illegal) thrown from behind the line may be touched by any eligible player. A pass in flight may be tipped, batted, or deflected in any direction by any eligible player at any time, including such a pass in
> the end zone.